# with jquery hide div when mouseout

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, mouseout

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu" id="atl-block">Menu-1</div>
    <div class="menu" id="btl-block">Menu-2</div>
    <div class="menu" id="ctl-block">Menu-3</div>
    <div class="menu" id="dtl-block">Menu-4</div>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn01">Click1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn02">Click2</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn03">Click3</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn04">Click4</a>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.menu {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#f00;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    display:none;    
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.wrapper').children('a').on('click',function(){
  $('.wrapper').children('div').hide().eq($(this).index()-4).fadeIn(400);
});
```

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SPYez/1/)**

When click any a tag in wrapper div, show related div. But I can't hide div when mouseout on the div. How can I do it?

Comment: Mouseout on the div or mouseout on the <a>?

Comment: Mouseout on the div @Anton

Comment: Not really a full answer just wanted to try some things with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/SPYez/5/. I would suggest cleaning it up a bit, if you can, the number of scans you are performing can be performed a bit more efficiently by linking your click object with the menu more conventionally. also the use of an anchor tag with a `javascript:void(0)` isnt very elegant where a span might be better suited, this means you dont need to worry about any `preventDefault` checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.menu').on('mouseout',function(){
$(this).hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SPYez/2/)

Comment: thanks @Anton well how can I hide this div when click any blank field?

Comment: blank field? Do you mean anywhere but <a> and and the <div>?

Comment: anywhere except  <div> when click hide div how?

Comment: thank you so much @Anton but I have a question. Listen click event for document can cause loss of performance?

Comment: I don't know :/ sry but i think it's the best way to do it otherwise `$(':not(".menu,a")').on('click',function(){
$('.menu').hide();
});`